GRPC client can not connect from ubuntu terminal
I have simple grpc client and server.
    public SensorRPCServer(ShareReadingsService service, int port) {
        this.service = service;
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void start() {
        try {
            server = ServerBuilder.forPort(port)
                    .addService(service)
                    .build()
                    .start();

            logger.info("Server started on " + port);

            //  Clean shutdown of server in case of JVM shutdown
            Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
                logger.severe("Shutting down gRPC server since JVM is shutting down");
                SensorRPCServer.this.stop();
            }));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.severe("GRPC server could not start up.");
        }
    }

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SensorRPCClient.class.getName());

    private final ManagedChannel channel;
    private final ShareReadingsGrpc.ShareReadingsBlockingStub blockingStub;

    public SensorRPCClient(String name, int port) {
        this.channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(name, port).usePlaintext().build();
        blockingStub = ShareReadingsGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);
    }

The client and the server are in the same project. Meaining a sensor is a client(fetching other sensors data) and a server(providing his readings to other sensors).
I build and run the java project from ubuntu terminal and pass the port for the grpc server to run on.
Build.gradle:
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '8.1.1'  // Add this line
    id 'com.google.protobuf' version '0.9.4'
}

group = 'labos1.labosi'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.json:json:20240303'
    implementation 'com.opencsv:opencsv:5.9'

    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-netty-shaded:1.68.0'
    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.68.0'
    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-services:1.68.0'
    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.68.0'
    implementation 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2'

    testImplementation platform('org.junit:junit-bom:5.10.0')
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

shadowJar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'labos1.labosi.Main'  // Change this to your main class
        )
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs 'build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc'
            srcDirs 'build/generated/source/proto/main/java'
        }
    }
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.25.5"
    }
    plugins {
        grpc {
            artifact = 'io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.68.0'
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all()*.plugins {
            grpc {}
        }
        all().each {
            it.group = 'build'
        }
    }
}

I run

./gradlew clean shadowjar
java -jar build/libs/sensor-1.0-SNAPSHOT-all.jar 3000

than if I start the second instance from intelij it connects to the grpc server on 3000 and works perfectly.
But if I start a second instance from terminal
java -jar build/libs/sensor-1.0-SNAPSHOT-all.jar 3001
When the grpc client tries to connect to grpc server on 3000 it fails.
INFO: Neighbour found: {"port":3000,"latitude":45.77,"ip":"127.0.0.1","longitude":15.96}
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Address types of NameResolver 'unix' for '127.0.0.1:3000' not supported by transport

public SensorRPCClient(String host, int port) {
 this.channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(host, port).usePlaintext().build(); <-- breaks here
 blockingStub = ShareReadingsGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel); 
 }

